# AngularJS default select option being removed from all select boxes on click in IE9

Tags: angularjs

IE9 isn't playing nice with my select boxes. When you click on one to change the value in Chrome it works as intended. In IE9 it's removing the default selection from every select box on the page. What the heck is happening here?

I had to do a jsfiddle this time becuase plunker doesn't seem to link IE9 either.

http://jsfiddle.net/sonicparke/nEDfY/

Here's one section of the code I'm using for the select boxes. There's a working example in the fiddle.

```
<select ng-model="initialOption1" ng-options="drafter.name for drafter in drafterItems"><option value="">Initial Option</option></select>
  <select ng-model="initialOption2" ng-options="drafter.name for drafter in drafterItems"><option value="">Initial Option</option></select>
  <select ng-model="initialOption3" ng-options="drafter.name for drafter in drafterItems"><option value="">Initial Option</option></select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what the cause is, but you can make it work by not using the initial option in the markup. Instead set a default in your ngOptions object and set the model values to that.

http://jsfiddle.net/Z2gkg/

```
$scope.initialOption1 = $scope.drafterItems[0];
$scope.initialOption2 = $scope.drafterItems[0];
$scope.initialOption3 = $scope.drafterItems[0];
```

I would love to know the underlying cause, but it is likely related to the ng-grid library you are including.